# i am using Ext.util.JSON.encode in view and i get error while compile time in cmd

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch

In my view file:

```
var jsonSRdata=**Ext.util.JSON.encode**(jsondata);
```

i got error in compile time as below.

```
[ERR] C2008: Requirement had no matching files (Ext.util.JSON) -- D:\wamp\www\xyz\app.js:17:87
[ERR]
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExBuild: Failed to find any files for D:\wamp\www\xyz\app.js::ClassRequire::Ext.util.JSON
[ERR]
[ERR] Total time: 14 seconds
[ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\wamp\www\xyz\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:367: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\wamp\www\xyz\.sencha\app\js-impl.xml:11: com.sencha.exceptions.ExBuild: Failed to find any files for D:\wamp\www\xyz\app.js::ClassRequire::Ext.util.JSON
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the Ans:

```
use Ext.JSON.encode(jsondata); this insted of Ext.util.JSON.encode(jsondata);
```